# Sending additonal data with document/form sent to the Records Center

Tags: 2010, workflow, records-management, records-center

I currently have a form that employees can fill out to request changes to ISO controlled documents, this form/form library is located under **site A**.

I have been asked that after the requested changes gets final approval or a single rejection that I make a record of the document, however the form does require further editing by members of QA team.  Since the form still has to be edited after approval I decided to send a copy of the document to the records center after approval/rejection. The records center is located under a different site which I will call **site B**

I have the records center set up, and it routes the form into the proper library.  However, I noticed that it only has the name linked to the form and modified/modified by columns. I want to make it so that I can populate additional columns in my records library automatically so searching for records will be easier for end users.

Since **site B** is a sub-site of **site A** my workflow on the original form/library can not update the records library in **site B**.

Is there a way to automatically fill in columns on the record library with data found in the form/original workflow?